# How to remove duplicates from a JavaScript Array case-insensitively?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say I have an array like:

`['A', 'b', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'D']`

How would I go about removing all but first occurrences in a case-insensitive way? In other words, the resulting array should then be:

`['A', 'b', 'c', 'D']`

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: look into using `Set`

Comment: There are many questions and answers on StackOverflow about filtering arrays to unique values. Have you tried searching for and adapting one of those?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have elegantly solved this problem using all the suggestions in this thread. I do appreciate what you said - was never my intention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an empty array for result. Then loop through the main array. Check whether the current item exists or not in the result array. If not exists just push the item to the array.

You can try the following with `forEach()` and `includes()`:

```js
var arr = ['A', 'b', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'D'];
var res = [];
arr.forEach(function(i){
  if(!(res.includes(i) || res.includes(i.toLowerCase())))
   res.push(i)
});
console.log(res);
```